# Reading multiple csv files into single DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to read multiple csv stock price files all of which have following columns: Date,Time, Open, High, Low, Close. The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
tickers=['gmk','yandex','sberbank']
ohlc_intraday={}
ohlc_intraday['gmk']=pd.read_csv("gmk_15min.csv",parse_dates=["<DATE>"],dayfirst=True)
ohlc_intraday['yandex']=pd.read_csv("yndx_15min.csv",parse_dates=["<DATE>"],dayfirst=True)
ohlc_intraday['sberbank']=pd.read_csv("sber_15min.csv",parse_dates=["<DATE>"],dayfirst=True)

df=copy.deepcopy(ohlc_intraday)

for i in range(len(tickers)):
    df[tickers[i]] = df[tickers[i]].iloc[:, 2:]
    df[tickers[i]].columns = ['Date','Time',"Open", "High", "Low", "Adj Close", "Volume"]
    df[tickers[i]]['Time']=[x+':00' for x in df['Time']]
```

However, I am then faced with the KeyError: 'Time'. Seems like columns are not keys.
Is it possible to read or convert it to a DataFrame format with keys being stock tickers (gmk, yandex, sberbank) and column names, so I can easily extract value using following code

```
ohlc_intraday['sberbank']['Date'][1]
```

Comment: The current code should allow that kind of extraction. What is the real question?

Comment: Whe I type ohlc_intraday['sberbank']['Time'] it brings up KeyError: 'Time' (and it definitely has Time column)

Comment: Please show the output of `ohlc_intraday['sberbank'].columns`.

Comment: Found mistake - forgot to put [tickers[i]] in front of df in the last row.
Thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a DataFrame that has a column that specifies the market.

```
import pandas as pd

markets = ["gmk", "yandex", "sberbank"]
markets = ["gmk_15min.csv", "yndx_15min.csv", "sberbank.csv"]

dfs = [pd.read_csv(market, parse_dates=["<DATE>"], dayfirst=True)
       for market in markets]

# add market column to each df
for df in dfs:
    df['market'] = market

# concatenate in one dataframe
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Then access what you want in this manner

```
df[df['market'] == 'yandex']['Date'].iloc[1]
```